# How do I use PowerShell's Where-Object to filter on property length?

Tags: arrays, powershell, where-clause

Say you have a PowerShell command, Get-MyObj. This returns objects that have a property named V that is an array of objects itself. How would you use Where-Object to select just the returned objects whose V property has length greater than 0?

I have tried the following which does not seem to work:

```
Where-Object($_.V.length -gt 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets, `{}`, instead of parentheses, `()`, for the filter clause:

```
Get-MyObj | Where-Object { $_.V.Length -gt 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (the solution of the pipe is more elegant, I find):

```
(Get-MyObj).Where({$_.V.Length -gt 0})
```